# Ceiling Fan update with Metal Sheathed Cables and Romex

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I have a few questions here. I was checking out my ceiling fan to see if I could install a separate switch for the fan and the light. When I got into the attic, this is what I found. Questions..

1. I assume this box is suitable for a fan?
2. I think the three wires coming in are metallic sheathed cable and if so, shouldn't they be used with a metal box?
3. The one cable looks like it has some damage on the cable, should these be replaced with Romex and be updated?
4. Lastly, can both types of cable be used together like this?

Thanks for the advice.

[image]

Comment: That box is NOT suitable for a ceiling fan. The weight of the fan needs to be transferred to the joists.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have access to the box from above a ceiling fan box would be a good and easy replacement.

[image]

The wires only look like they have metallic sheathed, they are not.

If you feel strongly about damage to the wire you can always replace it. As long as the insulation on the inner conductors is not damaged the wire should be fine.

Yes, the two kinds of wires can be used together.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the wires were metallic or not because all of my outlet boxes in the house expansion that was done in 2000 have metal boxes. I guess that is why I made the assumption these were. Thanks for the help.